# I have error to insert Image in this code

Tags: php, arrays, string, html

```
<?php
        $fortressMapping = [
            1 => <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>">,'JG Fortress',
            3 => <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>">,'HT Fortress',
            4 => <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>">,'Ban Fortress',
            6 => <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>">,'Ban Fortress',
    ];
```

How can I insert image in this code

Comment: What is the error? Where/how is `$fortressMapping` used? You shouldn't have `<?php` inside an open `<?php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it like this to add element to your array, **[live demo](https://eval.in/806667)**

```
<?php
    $fortressMapping = [
       1 => "<img src=\"<?php echo $image_url;?>\">,'JG Fortress'",
            .....
    ];
```

Comment: I don't need all one image, I need everyone has another image

Comment: I just make a example, you need to add the others yourself

Answer (score 0):

Remove echo inside `$fortressMapping`

```
<?php
$image_url = "http://example.com/image.png";
        $fortressMapping = [
            1 => '<img src="$image_url">','JG Fortress',
            3 => '<img src="$image_url">','HT Fortress',
            4 => '<img src="$image_url">','Ban Fortress',
            6 => '<img src="$image_url">','Ban Fortress',
    ];

    print_r($fortressMapping);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo inside the var assignment:

```
$fortressMapping = [
            1 => "<img src='{$image_url}'>",'JG Fortress',
            3 => "<img src='{$image_url}'>",'HT Fortress',
            4 => "<img src='{$image_url}'>",'Ban Fortress',
            6 => "<img src='{$image_url}'>",'Ban Fortress',
    ];
```